# A tricky integral problem depending on a parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I suggest directly see "my confusion" part and the last line of my solution to get a quick understand to save your time.

When I was learning the improper integral depending on a parameter chapter in the mathematical analysis lesson, I met this problem which comes from *Mathematical Analysis III by Senlin Xu* when I was doing its execise.
I almost solve the whole question while there still has some confusion I can't figure out. I don't want to give it up for already spending an afternoon on it.

---

> **Question.** calculate the integral $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(\alpha^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x,\quad\beta\neq0.$$Answer
> is $\frac{\pi}{|\beta|}\ln(|\alpha|+|\beta|)$

---

My thread is using this rule $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}\mathrm{d}x$, and I devided into four step: (1), (2) proof that it satisfies the condtions of exchanging the derivative and integral, (3) find the derivative, (4) integrate.

**My counfusion** is concentrated on the last line of my solution.
First, why the correct answer has the absolute value sign, which step I ignore to add it?
Second, there is still a integral in last line I can't work out, how to deal with it or it is insoluble which means my solution is somewhere wrong?

---

**My Solution.**
(1) First, assume $\alpha \in [a, b] $ and let  $$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(\alpha^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$$

We have
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x$$

$\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x$ is uniformly convergent for $\alpha$. Because
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(\alpha^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x < \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(\max\{|a|,|b|\}^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$$

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x$ is uniformly convergent for $\forall \alpha \in [a, b] \,(0 \notin [a, b])$ and disvergent at $\alpha = 0$, because
$$|\int_{0}^{1}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x |= |\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(\alpha^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x| < |\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(\min\{|a|,|b|\}^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x|$$
$$|\int_{0}^{1}f(x,0)\mathrm{d}x |= |\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x| > |\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\ln(x)}{\beta^{2}}\mathrm{d}x|$$
So $I(\alpha)$ is uniformly convergent in any $[a, b] \, (0 \notin [a, b])$.

(2) Find the partia derivative of $f(x, \alpha)$ for $\alpha$
$$\frac{\partial f(x, \alpha)}{\partial\alpha}=\frac\partial{\partial\alpha}(\frac{\ln(\alpha^2+x^2)}{\beta^2+x^2})=\frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha^2+x^2)(\beta^2+x^2)}$$

According to the maximum value theorem, $\exists \alpha_0 \in [a, b]$, make $|\frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha^2+x^2)(\beta^2+x^2)}| \leqslant|\frac{2\alpha_0}{(\alpha_0^2+x^2)(\beta^2+x^2)}|$.
Because
$$\operatorname*{lim}_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\frac{2\alpha_0}{(\alpha_0^{2}+x^{2})(\beta^{2}+x^{2})}}{\frac{1}{x^{4}}}=1$$
So $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x, \alpha)}{\partial\alpha}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac\partial{\partial\alpha}(\frac{\ln(\alpha^2+x^2)}{\beta^2+x^2})\mathrm{d}x$ is uniformly convergent for $\alpha$.
Also, $f(x, \alpha)$, $\frac{\partial f(x, \alpha)}{\partial\alpha}$ is continuous at $(0, +\infty)\times[a,b]$

(3) For now, assume $\alpha \in [a, b]$, we can use this rule $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)\mathrm{d}x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}\mathrm{d}x$. And we obtain
$$while\,\beta\neq\alpha,\,I'(\alpha)
=\frac{d}{d\alpha}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)dx)
=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,\alpha)}{\partial\alpha}dx
=\frac{2\alpha}{\beta^{2}-\alpha^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\alpha^{2}+x^2}-\frac{1}{\beta^{2}+x^2})dx
=\frac{2\alpha}{\beta^{2}-\alpha^{2}}(\frac{1}{\alpha}\arctan(\frac{x}{\alpha})-\frac{1}{\beta}\tan(\frac{x}{\beta}))|_{0}^{+\infty}
=\frac{\pi}{(\beta+\alpha)\beta}$$
$$while\,\beta=\alpha,\,I'(\beta)=2\beta\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(\beta^2+x)^2}=2\beta\left.(\frac{(x^2+\beta^2)\arctan\frac x2+\beta x}{2\beta^3x^2+2\beta^5})\right|_{0}^{+\infty}=2\beta\frac{\frac\pi2}{2\beta^3}=\frac\pi{\beta^2}
$$
In general, $I'(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{(\beta+\alpha)\beta}$.

(4) So we can get
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{\beta}^{\alpha}\frac{\pi}{(\beta+t)\beta}dt+I(\beta)=\frac{\pi}{\beta}\ln(\alpha+\beta)-\frac{\pi}{\beta}\ln(2\beta)+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(\beta^{2}+x^{2})}{\beta^{2}+x^{2}}dx$$